# 'ls' command in Bash - Matching numericals

Tags: linux, bash, ls

I have a directory with the following files:

```
root.o
root.type1
root.type2
root.type1.c
root.type2.c
root.type1.c.pa0
root.type2.c.pa0
root.type2.c.pa1
root.type2.c.pa2
root.type2.c.pa3
....
root.type2.c.pa100
root.type2.c.pa0.out
root.type2.c.pa1.out
root.type2.c.pa2.out
root.type2.c.pa3.out
...
root.type2.c.pa100.out
```

I would like to list the files that begin with `root.type2.c.pa.` and end with numbers, excluding the files ending with `.out`. In other words, I want to list this chunk :

```
root.type2.c.pa0
root.type2.c.pa1
root.type2.c.pa2
root.type2.c.pa3
....
root.type2.c.pa100
```

Writing `ls root.type2.c.pa?`, `ls root.type2.c.pa??`, and `ls root.type2.c.pa???` would do the job.

Is their a simple way to list the chunk without knowing how many numbers there are at the end of the desired files ? In the example above, we have at most 3 numbers. In practice, I may have 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5 numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
shopt -s extglob
ls root.type2.c.pa+([0-9])
```

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html

Answer (score 0):

Use grep and regular expressions:

```
ls |grep -P "root.type2.c.pa[0-9]+$"
```

Comment: This also matches files like `blah.root.type2.c.pa01` and breaks for files with newlines in their names.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ls -1 | grep -oP "root.type2.c.pa\d{1,}"
```

Comment: That also matches the file `something.root.type2.c.pa01`, and you don't need `-1` if you're piping `ls`, and you shouldn't parse the output of `ls` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

When the command line contains shell wildcards (`*`, `?`, `[...]`), the list of file names listed by `ls` is not decided by `ls`. The shell expands the wildcards and passes to `ls` the list of file names that match. `ls` only displays the file names with or without other details (size, owner, permission, dates etc).

A possible solution is to use wildcards to compose a command line for `ls` that includes all the required files (and possibly other files) then pipe the output to `grep` and use it to filter only the desired files:

```
ls -1 root.type2.c.pa* | grep '^root\.type2\.c\.pa\d\+$'
```

How it works:

- `ls -1 root.type2.c.pa*` - lists all the files whose name start with `root.type2.c.pa`; `-1` tells `ls` to display each file name on a separate line;
- `grep '^root\.type2\.c\.pa\d\+$'` filters the output of `ls` and keeps only the names that start with `root.type2.c.pa` followed by at least one digit (`\d\+`) and nothing else (`$` is the end of line).